# VSTO: Is there any way to retrieve the original file name of a picture (InlineShape) that has been inserted into a document?

Tags: c#, file, vsto, image

I am developing a Word Addin. There is a piece of functionality within the Addin that is required to retireive the original location of a picture that has been inserted into a document.

It doesn't matter if the Image file no longer exists in the original directory. I will handle that in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do this. I did had the same requirement to find the file name from the image in the document. So I had to insert the image with the file name in its alternative text description to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I found a way around it that I didn't need the original file location.

Answer (score 1):

The question got me curious, so I tried the following: add an image to a word document, save it, zip it and start looking into the xml document. The **media** folder contains the image as embedded in word, which at that point has been renamed and "forgot" about its origin. On the other hand, **document.xml** does contain a lot of information about the image enclosed in the  tag, and that includes the whole path to the original picture.

I don't know if the Open XML SDK gives you directly access to this (doubt it), but worst case you should be able to get to it by digging into the file, assuming you are working with an already-saved file.

If the file is not saved yet, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up managing the requirement in a different way. Not ideal but it works for what I want it to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years old, but the full path of an image that has been drag&dropped into a document is available in the `AlternativeText` field of the `InlineShape`. Unfortunately you cannot get this value when it has been inserted with `Insert Picture`. Images that have been pasted probably vary on whether this is available, e.g. if it was pasted from a document where it was drag&dropped it's probably there, but otherwise it isn't.

This info comes from targeting Word 2010 with VSTO.